# Should "hi," "thanks," taglines and salutations be removed from posts?

Tags: discussion

Exactly as per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) on StackOverflow.

I just edited a question to remove a "thanks" message as per the asking guidelines on SO; however, it occurs to me that this is effectively a site-specific guideline and may not apply on Tridion StackExchange. Since this doesn't appear to have been discussed yet; discuss!

Personally, I am in agreement with the consensus on StackOverflow that it adds unnecessary clutter to what *should* essentially be an evolving, collective resource of information. I'd say this kind of thing is exactly what the comments are for (barring the obvious spamming of "thanks!" on popular questions).

Comment: I would also argue that for issues like this, the discussions on Meta Stack Overflow cover the entire network, not just Stack Overflow. As an aside, MSO is going to be split into two sites at some point in the near future so that Stack Overflow has its own Meta site and there is also a Meta site for the network as a whole.

Comment: It's an information-hiding thing. If you don't rule explicitly for your own site, generic SO guidelines apply.

Answer (score 6):

Others may disagree but I'm happy to follow Stack Overflow  on this.

Though the edited will initially balk at the removal of courtesies such as these, they add nothing to the content as a resource of knowledge. Their use is very forum-esque.

I tend not to edit them out myself any more as they are good targets for new users to suggest edits and get involved ;-)

Comment: Agree with both your points on this.